# how to HLS(Http Live Strem) with Nginx

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, raspberry-pi, http-live-streaming

I stream video in a RaspberryPi into `/run/shm/hls/index.m3u8`. and i want stream them to http. I use Nginx and configured it accourding to `nginx.org`:

```
location /hls {
    hls;
    hls_fragment            5s;
    hls_buffers             10 10m;
    hls_mp4_buffer_size     1m;
    hls_mp4_max_buffer_size 5m;
    root /run/shm;
}
```

when I run nginx I get the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "hls" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:62
```

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `ngx_http_hls_module`, which is available with a *commercial subscription*, provides `HLS` support for `MP4` and `MOV` files. You already seem to have a `HLS` stream available so you don't need to pass trough this module at all. Just output your segments/playlist directly into a web accessible directory.

Concerning the shown error, it's most likely due to an error in the configuration file somewhere before your `location` directive. Check the entire config file.